# Spring MVC Themes Not working

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to execute a Spring MVC application that uses Spring MVC theme feature. I am following this example https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OiQql85qsos But somehow its not working, here is the project structure in STS

[image]

I just have a  HomeController

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

@RequestMapping("/")
public String getHomePage(){
    return "home";
}

}
```

Here is the web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
<display-name>SpringMVCThemes</display-name>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>config</servlet-name>
    <servlet-   class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>config</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Below is the config-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.1.xsd">

<mvc:annotation-driven></mvc:annotation-driven>
<context:component-scan base-package="co.edureka.controllers"/>  

<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/*" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/images/**" location="/resources/images/" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="/resources/css/" />  

<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean> 

<bean id="themeSource"
    class="org.springframework.ui.context.support.ResourceBundleThemeSource">
        <property name="basenamePrefix" value="META-INF.theme-" />
</bean>

<bean id="themeChangeInterceptor"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.theme.ThemeChangeInterceptor">
    <property name="paramName" value="theme" />
</bean> 
<bean id="themeResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.theme.CookieThemeResolver">
    <property name="defaultThemeName" value="default" />
</bean>

<mvc:interceptors>
<ref bean="themeChangeInterceptor"/>
</mvc:interceptors>

</beans>
```

Here is the content of theme-black.properties (under WebContent/META-INF)

```
css=resources/css/theme-black.css
```

Below is the content of theme-black.css (under WebContent/resources/css)

```
body {
background-color: #DBF5FF;
color: #007AAB;
}
```

Here is the home.jsp but on clicking on other themes link it does not change the themes

[image: home.jsp]

I checked the cookies , there is a cookie with name org.springframework.web.servlet.theme.CookieThemeResolver.THEME

How to make it work ?

Comment: Your configuration is wrong... Remove the `DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping` and use `<mvc:interceptors />` to register the interceptors.

Comment: @M.Deinum thanks for that Now I can see the org.springframework.web.servlet.theme.CookieThemeResolver.THEME cookie in the browser but still its not taking themes.

Comment: I don't really get your application structure you apparently do something with maven, but the structure is based on eclipse? If you are using maven the properties file is in the wrong location and should be in `src/main/resources` if you aren't using maven it can be in whatever directory. Do you have the `<spring:theme />` tag in your tsp?

Comment: @M.Deinum I have edited the question and changed the project structure but its not taking themes from the css file. I am not using <spring:themes> tag in JSP , is it required. In some of the articles on web I don't see use of <spring:themes> tag.

Comment: Yes it is required, else nothing will be done with the selected theme... See http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-themeresolver .

Answer (score 1):

First off all your interceptor setup is flawed. You are using `<mvc:annotation-driven />` and as such should use the `<mvc:interceptors />` to register your interceptors. You should remove the `DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping` bean.

```
<mvc:interceptors>
    <ref bean="themeChangeInterceptor"/>
</mvc:interceptors>
```

Next to be able to use the selected theme in your JSP you have to use the `theme` tag from the Spring tag library.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
```

Then in your header include the stylesheet you want to use.

```
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<spring:theme code='styleSheet'/>" type="text/css"/>
</head>
```